# In Play 2.4.0 How to NAME a Field in a multi-field Constraint on a nested Form?

Tags: forms, scala, validation, constraints, playframework-2.4

This is a follow up to a question on complex Forms: [How to get child record (case class) ID in Play Framework (2.4.0) using Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651605/how-to-get-child-record-case-class-id-in-play-framework-2-0-4-using-forms)

```
lazy val aForm = Form(
mapping(
  "ID" -> ignored(id),
  "firstName" -> nonEmptyText,
  "lastName" -> nonEmptyText,
  "listOfEmails" -> mapping(
     "ID" -> ignored(emailID),
     "email" -> email,
     "userID" -> ignored(id),
     "emailTypeID" -> longNumber)
     (UserEmail.apply)(UserEmail.unapply) verifying someConstraint,
  "statusID" -> ignored(0l),
  "roleID" -> default(longNumber, roleID),
  "timezoneID" -> default(longNumber, timezoneID) 
  (User.apply) 
  (User.unapply)
  )
```

Now since the constraint is after the `apply` method we have the converted `case class` and access to all it's fields and as such we can write a validation that uses data from any and all fields. Not sure I'm really happy with that - why convert data before the test - why can't we simply use the data already at hand for the validation process? It also presents a problem if the `case class` itself has any exceptions in creation due to errant data or internal validation processes but that would be a small enough corner case to build a work-around for - a custom `case class` just for the validation.

```
   def someConstraint: Constraint[UserEmail] =  Constraint("constraints.unique")({
     userEmail =>
          match doStuff(userEmail.ID, userEmail.email, userEmail. emailTypeID) {
          case BAD => Invalid(Seq(ValidationError("error.unique.email.required")))
          case GOOD => Valid
          }
       }
    |)
```

Sorry for the pseudo code but hopefully you get the basic idea of what is happening in the validation process. We take several fields and process the data they contain to make the validation judgment call.

Here's the thing though.

On the HTML output the nested class fields must be referred to as: `listOfEmails[x].ID` and `listOfEmails[x].email` etc in order for the Play framework to capture them properly on the on a `POST` -- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0/ScalaForms

However the Constraint process returns `listOfEmails[x]` as the field name for the error key and as such it won't appear on the html template as that key doesn't match anything.

So how does one rename the error field key (assuming that is the correct answer here) or perhaps a better questions is how does one do this process play-matically end to end?

*Yes we can use global errors however on a large and complex form we want to get the error as close to the solution for the user's eyeballs to pick up and move forward quickly.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
object TestSeq extends App {
//case class Email(email: String)
  case class Email(email: String,f1:String,f2:String,f3:String,f4:String,f5:String,f6:String,f7:String,f8:String,f9:String)
  case class User(name: String, emails: Seq[Email], addr: String)

  import play.api.data.Forms._
  import play.api.data._
  import play.api.data.validation._

  val someConstraint: Constraint[Email] =
    Constraint("constraints.unique"){  email =>
      if(email.email.contains('@')) Valid
      else Invalid(ValidationError("error.unique.email.required"))
    }

  val form = Form(
    mapping(
      "name" -> text,
      "emails" -> seq(mapping(
        "email" -> nonEmptyText,
        "f1" -> text,
        "f2" -> text,
        "f3" -> text,
        "f4" -> text,
        "f5" -> text,
        "f6" -> text,
        "f7" -> text,
        "f8" -> text,
        "f9" -> text
      )(Email.apply)(Email.unapply) verifying someConstraint),
      "addr" -> text
    )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
  )

  val data = Map[String, String](
    "name" -> "xx",
    "emails[0].email" -> "a0@xx.com",
    "emails[0].f1" -> "0f1",
    "emails[0].f2" -> "0f2",
    "emails[0].f3" -> "0f3",
    "emails[0].f4" -> "0f4",
    "emails[0].f5" -> "0f5",
    "emails[0].f6" -> "0f6",
    "emails[0].f7" -> "0f7",
    "emails[0].f8" -> "0f8",
//    "emails[0].f9" -> "0f9",
    "emails[1].email" -> "",
    "emails[1].f1" -> "1f1",
    "emails[1].f2" -> "1f2",
    "emails[1].f3" -> "1f3",
    "emails[1].f4" -> "1f4",
    "emails[1].f5" -> "1f5",
    "emails[1].f6" -> "1f6",
    "emails[1].f7" -> "1f7",
    "emails[1].f8" -> "1f8",
    "emails[1].f9" -> "1f9",
    "emails[2].email" -> "a2xx.com",
    "emails[2].f1" -> "2f1",
    "emails[2].f2" -> "2f2",
    "emails[2].f3" -> "2f3",
    "emails[2].f4" -> "2f4",
    "emails[2].f5" -> "2f5",
    "emails[2].f6" -> "2f6",
    "emails[2].f7" -> "2f7",
    "emails[2].f8" -> "2f8",
    "emails[2].f9" -> "2f9",
    "addr" -> "dalian"
  )

  val user = form.bind(data).fold(
    ef => ef.errors.foreach(println _) ,
    contact =>println(contact)
  )

  /* ===== output =====
  FormError(emails[0].f9,List(error.required),List())
  FormError(emails[1].email,List(error.required),WrappedArray())
  FormError(emails[2],List(error.unique.email.required),WrappedArray())
  user: Unit = ()
  */
}
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer + it would be nice to provide some context and explanation for this code.

Comment: Essentially this has added `seq` to the mapping of the child case class. makes me wonder if I failed to put that in the sample code in the first place of not. I think I remember having horrible problems with trying to mix mutli-field case classes with `seq` (the example here is a SINGLE field case class)

Comment: """Essentially this has added seq to the mapping of the child case class.""" yes.
@Techmag I change the code to mutli-field.

Comment: Sorry I have not gotten back to this yet - deadlines :(  

It is however in the list of things I need to verify.